# ASP.NET MVC OAuth authentication with Jira?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, jira

I am building an ASP.NET MVC Application and I need to implement OAuth authentication with Jira.

In Jira Bitbucket repository there is an example of how to configure a client with Java and other languages, but nothing for C#.

Can anyone show me an example for a Jira OAuth Client in C#?

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/0c6b54f6fefe996535fb0bdb87ad937e5ffc402d/java/src/main/java/com/atlassian/oauth/client/example/?at=default

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-oauth-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

I have a project using this SDK from atlassian [Atlassian.NET SDK](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/master/README.md)
in order to get my work a little fast, it has an example of using the authentication

[Example of using SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk1qs.png)

```
var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient("http://<your_jira_server>", "<user>", "<password>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late. I came across the internet with the same issue but no luck. So I dug into the code and have such hacky way to achieve what I needed.
This is how I did for our project with the [Atlassian.NET SDK](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/src/master/README.md)

```
var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(JiraHost);
jira.RestClient.RestSharpClient.Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(_JiraToken, "Bearer");
var myself = await jira.Users.GetMyselfAsync();
```

Basically, the way to use oauth in this sdk is to override RestSharp object for the authentication. This could make the jira object to have enough permission to call the api.